# c# HttpClient just stops without any indication why

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to fetch data from our API instance. The code I have is pretty much copied MS website with teaks found on SO. The code that I am using is this:

```
string peopleEndpoint = $"{apiConf.ApiEndpoint}/{apiConf.dbspec}/_table/mdm.PEOPLE_SV";
string json = null;
try
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", apiConf.ApiKey);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(peopleEndpoint);
        json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

The configuration values are good... I can copy them and paste them into a cURL command and get the data. Same with the headers.

Now when I debug, execution stops after executing this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(peopleEndpoint);
```

And, in the output window, all I see is:

```
The program '[10172] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10172] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How can I figure out what is causing this failure?

The framework is noted as:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: what happens when you run it w/ a debugger? what platform?

Comment: I am developing this app so it is running in DEBUG. It is running on a VM with Win Server 2016 Standard. The host OS is Mac.

Comment: run it with a debugger, not just in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, the VS debugger.

Comment: what does that show as you step thru the code?

Comment: Nothing. It just stops.

Comment: How are you calling the async method that this code is in?

Comment: It is called using `await` and the method itself is async.

Comment: Is the code async all the way to the top or is there a non async method that calls this code somewhere that may not be waiting until it is complete. That's kind of what this smells like to me.

Comment: Or remove all `try.. catch` from your code.

Comment: @MattiPrice Yes, that is it! Thank you!

Comment: I'll put that as an answer just to get the question closed out. Thought that was what it might be

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but you shouldn't use HttpClient in a using statement. And since you are using .NET Core 2.1 you can use the new HttpClientFactory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the code async all the way to the top or is there a non async method that calls this code somewhere that may not be waiting until it is complete. That's kind of what this smells like to me.